# Creating some Value by constructor and trying to add to Document does not work using rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am starting to use rapidjson and I am testing the following example, based on the rapidjson [tutorial](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html):

```
// Create an empty document:
Document d; // Null
d.SetObject();

// Create an empty value:
Value v;    // Null
// Give it an int value:
v.SetInt(10);

// Create additonal values:
Value a3(123);
Value b(456);
```

Now, I want to add these `Value` objects (`v`, `a3`, `b`) to the document `d` and print the content of `d`.

I think the code to use would look something like this:

```
// This is not syntactically correct:
d.AddMember(v, d.GetAllocator());

// This is not syntactically correct:
d.AddMember(a3, d.GetAllocator());

// This is not syntactically correct:
d.AddMember(b, d.GetAllocator());

// Now I print on the screen the content of d.
StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
d.Accept(writer);
std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;
```

Here, the problem is that the `AddMember` functions wait to receive three parameters.

What is the correct way to add these Value objects to the document?

I have tested the method to print a JSON Document with other examples, and it works, but on these examples, I have created the document by parsing a JSON string. Now, I need to create the document from `Value` objects, without parsing a string.

Answer (score 1):

`AddMember` needs three arguments i.e. key, value, and allocator.

Here's a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace rapidjson;

    Document doc;
    doc.SetObject();

    Value v1;
    v1.SetInt( 123 );

    Value v2( 456 );
    Value v3( 789 );

    doc.AddMember( "v1", v1, doc.GetAllocator() );
    doc.AddMember( "v2", v2, doc.GetAllocator() );
    doc.AddMember( "v3", v3, doc.GetAllocator() );

    StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer( buffer );
    doc.Accept( writer );

    std::cout << buffer.GetString() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{"v1":123,"v2":456,"v3":789}
```